# rotate animation on selected part of the svg that contains paths

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have this picture of what my svg looks like (I created it with illustrator)
[image]

what I want is to rotate animate the upper part circle line of the circle (it has 4 circle lines, lets say the number one circle line start from the bottom inside the circle) from left to right and next circle line of the upper circle line from right to left. Below is the code of my svg.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="700px" height="700px" viewBox="0 0 3000 3000" enable-background="new 0 0 3000 3000" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1375.631,54"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1375.631,54
                C633.068,117.25,50.095,740.004,50.095,1498.942s582.974,1381.693,1325.536,1444.94"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1625.068,2943.882
                c742.562-63.251,1325.534-686.003,1325.534-1444.94S2367.63,117.25,1625.068,54"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1625.068,2943.882"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1625.068,54"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M357.221,1395.021"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M2643.479,1440.251h77.141
                c-30.628-647.454-565.236-1162.983-1220.269-1162.983c-655.036,0-1189.644,515.529-1220.271,1162.983h77.142"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M2643.479,1440.251"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M357.221,1557.633"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M357.221,1557.633h-77.142
                c30.627,647.452,565.235,1162.982,1220.271,1162.982c655.032,0,1189.641-515.53,1220.269-1162.982h-77.141"/>
        </g>
        <g id="XMLID_1_">
            <g>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2903.798,1498.94c0,15.417-0.269,30.797-0.758,46.129h-122.333c0.551-15.308,0.831-30.688,0.831-46.129
                    c0-53.941-3.361-107.1-9.866-159.304l120.658-21.286C2899.959,1377.854,2903.798,1438.104,2903.798,1498.94z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2779.937,1563.408h122.407c-3.338,74.248-12.422,147.519-27.228,219.505l-120.67-21.273
                    C2767.931,1697.185,2776.575,1630.98,2779.937,1563.408z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2889.885,1300.158l-120.608,21.273c-9.341-67.121-23.914-132.591-43.28-195.995l115.327-41.972
                    C2863.281,1154.303,2879.48,1226.644,2889.885,1300.158z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2750.558,1779.575l120.744,21.285c-15.674,71.474-36.983,141.65-63.893,210.214l-115.23-41.936
                    C2716.35,1908.095,2735.936,1844.764,2750.558,1779.575z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2835.761,1065.97l-115.242,41.947c-20.784-64.688-46.568-127.15-76.913-186.922l106.39-61.436
                    c15.649,30.528,30.174,61.594,43.488,93.076C2809.267,989.937,2823.352,1027.727,2835.761,1065.97z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2685.296,1986.146l115.303,41.972c-2.335,5.722-4.694,11.431-7.115,17.128
                    c-25.895,61.253-56.35,120.891-90.839,178.035l-106.317-61.375C2630.291,2105.972,2660.086,2047.238,2685.296,1986.146z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2741.511,843.286l-106.329,61.387c-31.788-60.47-68.27-118.103-108.97-172.423l94.2-79.041
                    c15.1,19.977,29.686,40.309,43.672,61.008C2692.154,755.772,2718.024,798.93,2741.511,843.286z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2586.693,2177.519l106.366,61.411c-9.378,15.099-19.036,30.026-28.976,44.747
                    c-30.639,45.334-64.052,89.017-99.874,130.622l-94.104-78.968C2512.824,2285.877,2551.837,2233.122,2586.693,2177.519z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2609.25,638.648l-94.152,79.004c-42.008-54.442-88.296-105.412-138.349-152.421l79.09-94.25
                    c12.52,11.639,24.831,23.499,36.897,35.565C2534.231,548.041,2573.196,592.263,2609.25,638.648z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2458.027,2349.134l94.128,78.992c-19.171,21.677-38.989,42.779-59.419,63.208
                    c-36.151,36.152-74.37,70.41-114.3,102.467l-78.98-94.116C2356.479,2454.058,2409.551,2403.687,2458.027,2349.134z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2442.305,458.572l-79.028,94.176c-56.374-51.459-117.357-97.954-182.24-138.801l61.435-106.402
                    c14.378,8.974,28.585,18.192,42.608,27.667C2340.193,372.452,2392.863,413.788,2442.305,458.572z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2285.055,2511.043l79.004,94.152c-25.687,20.087-52.046,39.281-78.979,57.486
                    c-33.084,22.349-67.182,43.304-102.1,62.768l-61.362-106.28C2178.933,2587.26,2233.546,2551.07,2285.055,2511.043z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2226.834,297.935l-61.387,106.329c-58.696-35.785-120.486-66.986-184.856-93.113l41.96-115.254
                    c8.057,3.24,16.089,6.517,24.109,9.903C2108.67,232.037,2169.029,262.919,2226.834,297.935z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2105.528,2627.972l61.374,106.305c-39.196,21.188-79.358,40.518-120.242,57.805
                    c-25.626,10.845-51.483,20.87-77.562,30.112l-41.911-115.156C1988.929,2685.152,2048.506,2658.646,2105.528,2627.972z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2005.471,189.172l-41.935,115.205c-64.053-24.917-130.586-44.833-199.125-59.247l21.273-120.67
                    C1860.459,139.902,1933.826,161.505,2005.471,189.172z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1909.852,2713.04l41.923,115.181c-68.331,23.242-138.129,41.055-209.101,53.403l-21.261-120.597
                    C1786.002,2749.755,1848.954,2733.629,1909.852,2713.04z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1767.7,120.866l-21.273,120.609c-67.438-13.167-136.747-21.029-207.486-23.131V96.023
                    C1616.318,98.089,1692.682,106.402,1767.7,120.866z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1703.318,2764.06l21.261,120.584c-61.093,9.793-123.03,15.552-185.639,17.227v-122.32
                    C1594.69,2777.887,1649.561,2772.642,1703.318,2764.06z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1520.602,2779.965v122.284c-6.749,0.086-13.498,0.146-20.247,0.146
                    c-68.135,0-135.525-4.816-201.961-14.377l21.273-120.585c59.039,8.362,119.362,12.703,180.688,12.703
                    C1507.116,2780.137,1513.864,2780.075,1520.602,2779.965z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1520.602,95.644v122.284c-6.737-0.11-13.485-0.183-20.247-0.183c-76.375,0-151.199,6.736-223.931,19.61
                    l-21.273-120.597c80.374-14.146,162.239-21.273,245.204-21.273C1507.104,95.485,1513.864,95.546,1520.602,95.644z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1301.512,2764.72l-21.261,120.572c-73.821-11.615-146.431-29.11-217.476-52.449l41.935-115.206
                    C1168.285,2738.336,1234.037,2754.156,1301.512,2764.72z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1237.118,120.059l21.261,120.609c-71.473,13.718-140.843,33.401-207.584,58.501l-41.923-115.193
                    C1083.242,156.138,1159.458,134.792,1237.118,120.059z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1087.301,2711.83l-41.911,115.168c-30.761-10.551-61.216-22.165-91.353-34.917
                    c-38.867-16.444-77.085-34.734-114.435-54.699l61.374-106.305C960.468,2662.706,1022.735,2689.774,1087.301,2711.83z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M991.73,190.529l41.935,115.206c-67.194,26.383-131.649,58.281-192.779,95.13L779.5,294.56
                    c56.093-33.621,114.545-63.379,174.538-88.76C966.544,200.518,979.113,195.432,991.73,190.529z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M884.838,2622.348l-61.362,106.28c-36.923-20.368-72.953-42.375-107.858-65.946
                    c-20.943-14.158-41.531-28.927-61.729-44.222l79.041-94.201C781.064,2560.374,831.814,2593.177,884.838,2622.348z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M763.826,304.097l61.411,106.354c-60.788,37.827-118.188,80.618-171.628,127.786l-78.98-94.127
                    c44.686-39.246,91.866-75.703,140.99-108.897C731.464,324.514,747.553,314.146,763.826,304.097z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M718.321,2513.121l-78.992,94.152c-46.128-35.884-90.105-74.664-131.368-115.939
                    c-11.859-11.858-23.511-23.938-34.954-36.225l94.262-79.103C613.899,2425.583,664.404,2471.455,718.321,2513.121z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M560.912,456.31l79.016,94.152c-47.241,42.889-91.254,89.262-131.673,138.679l-94.091-78.955
                    c29.55-36.079,60.873-70.715,93.798-103.64C525.15,489.356,542.829,472.607,560.912,456.31z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M554.774,2362.546l-94.189,79.041c-45.016-49.649-86.56-102.552-123.971-157.91
                    c-4.976-7.373-9.854-14.794-14.695-22.264l106.476-61.473C466.172,2257.525,508.474,2311.894,554.774,2362.546z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M402.622,624.454l94.127,78.979c-44.258,55.702-83.968,115.157-118.592,177.814l-106.28-61.362
                    c20.026-36.165,41.629-71.461,64.736-105.669C357.374,683.493,379.429,653.527,402.622,624.454z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M418.43,2184.512l-106.391,61.436c-40.297-63.979-75.483-131.307-104.825-200.702
                    c-0.379-0.88-0.734-1.76-1.101-2.641l115.364-41.996C348.876,2064.758,381.373,2126.218,418.43,2184.512z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M263.087,835.987l106.305,61.375c-33.291,62.34-61.582,127.737-84.322,195.652l-115.218-41.935
                    c11.175-33.169,23.633-65.996,37.363-98.443C223.976,912.999,242.657,874.047,263.087,835.987z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M314.375,1983.676l-115.267,41.959c-29.085-71.754-52.009-145.293-68.722-220.275l120.768-21.297
                    C266.84,1852.857,288.077,1919.563,314.375,1983.676z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M164.105,1068.513l115.267,41.948c-21.249,66.619-37.191,135.586-47.302,206.411l-120.597-21.261
                    C122.647,1218.477,140.191,1142.651,164.105,1068.513z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M247.206,1766.139l-120.695,21.286c-15.344-73.441-24.746-148.229-28.157-224.017h122.407
                    C224.208,1632.558,233.17,1700.277,247.206,1766.139z"/>
                <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M108.966,1313.791l120.622,21.273c-6.883,53.672-10.429,108.371-10.429,163.877
                    c0,15.441,0.281,30.821,0.831,46.129H97.657c-0.489-15.332-0.758-30.712-0.758-46.129
                    C96.899,1436.551,100.946,1374.773,108.966,1313.791z"/>
            </g>
            <g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M714.827,655.783c11.458-10.68,23.14-21.121,35.024-31.334l-15.507-19.669
                c-12.194,10.472-24.206,21.196-36.011,32.197L714.827,655.783z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M763.862,612.598c12.066-10.043,24.33-19.854,36.803-29.407l-14.468-20.471
                c-12.806,9.794-25.414,19.873-37.839,30.211L763.862,612.598z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M624.686,749.812c10.139-11.834,20.502-23.47,31.103-34.881l-17.471-17.935
                c-10.941,11.743-21.607,23.689-32.024,35.815L624.686,749.812z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M511.15,907.297c7.944-13.233,16.137-26.299,24.59-39.182l-20.097-15.006
                c-8.707,13.253-17.127,26.691-25.289,40.292L511.15,907.297z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M583.821,800.284c9.433-12.346,19.11-24.493,29.024-36.44l-18.404-17.013
                c-10.229,12.288-20.208,24.754-29.902,37.416L583.821,800.284z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M479.525,963.445c7.167-13.606,14.6-27.049,22.288-40.327l-20.789-13.89
                c-7.907,13.66-15.561,27.478-22.923,41.47L479.525,963.445z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M451.192,1021.114c6.369-13.93,13.011-27.71,19.913-41.336l-21.417-12.742
                c-7.096,14.013-13.917,28.188-20.468,42.518L451.192,1021.114z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M545.939,852.842c8.701-12.812,17.659-25.435,26.855-37.873l-19.293-16.045
                c-9.482,12.794-18.696,25.771-27.639,38.928L545.939,852.842z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M924.925,500.173c13.651-7.895,27.481-15.517,41.478-22.862l-11.009-22.323
                c-14.395,7.517-28.62,15.319-42.664,23.411L924.925,500.173z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M421.698,1026.322c-2.088,4.762-4.153,9.538-6.181,14.333c-49.052,115.971-78.764,237.712-88.737,363.029
                h24.582c10.607-129.072,42.545-252.194,92.308-365.804L421.698,1026.322z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2649.337,1594.199c-14.892,181.217-71.867,350.691-161.118,498.604l22.143,11.651
                c28.249-47.074,53.238-96.199,74.821-147.227c49.051-115.972,78.764-237.713,88.736-363.028H2649.337z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M668.395,701.584c10.813-11.277,21.856-22.334,33.116-33.167l-16.5-18.813
                c-5.772,5.546-11.508,11.143-17.184,16.817c-5.697,5.698-11.315,11.457-16.882,17.252L668.395,701.584z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1094.746,393.312l8.554,23.185c14.823-5.455,29.793-10.602,44.893-15.458l-7.327-23.594
                C1125.403,382.407,1110.029,387.696,1094.746,393.312z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M982.714,468.923c14.093-7.11,28.343-13.955,42.758-20.497l-9.788-22.779
                c-14.826,6.697-29.476,13.704-43.964,20.984L982.714,468.923z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1042.238,440.99c14.483-6.297,29.123-12.298,43.906-18.009l-8.56-23.2
                c-11.896,4.584-23.742,9.346-35.523,14.328c-3.21,1.357-6.403,2.744-9.599,4.129L1042.238,440.99z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M869.068,534.63c13.164-8.647,26.523-17.022,40.055-25.138l-12.21-21.801
                C883,496,869.26,504.583,855.71,513.461L869.068,534.63z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M815.328,572.162c12.636-9.364,25.465-18.48,38.488-27.333l-13.369-21.186
                c-13.38,9.071-26.574,18.427-39.58,28.057L815.328,572.162z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2447.525,2155.576c-7.213,10.371-14.592,20.611-22.13,30.73l20.854,13.936
                c7.796-10.49,15.42-21.095,22.854-31.828L2447.525,2155.576z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2302.807,2325.975c-8.901,8.639-17.933,17.145-27.109,25.497l17.455,17.918
                c9.47-8.641,18.817-17.45,28.038-26.424L2302.807,2325.975z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2414.304,2200.953c-7.667,9.958-15.492,19.789-23.472,29.486l20.082,14.996
                c8.265-10.052,16.355-20.23,24.266-30.531L2414.304,2200.953z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2341.849,2286.224c-8.513,9.092-17.163,18.054-25.961,26.865l18.36,16.972
                c9.121-9.147,18.071-18.421,26.857-27.822L2341.849,2286.224z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2379.047,2244.527c-8.102,9.531-16.348,18.936-24.748,28.195l19.244,16.006
                c8.705-9.605,17.237-19.339,25.6-29.195L2379.047,2244.527z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1832.029,2603.217c-105.083,31.622-216.431,48.635-331.68,48.635
                c-603.643,0-1100.398-466.33-1148.989-1057.652h-24.582c9.974,125.315,39.686,247.057,88.737,363.028
                c59.299,140.2,144.19,266.11,252.312,374.233c108.124,108.124,234.035,193.012,374.234,252.315
                c145.16,61.396,299.35,92.527,458.288,92.527c116.091,0,229.645-16.63,339.001-49.513L1832.029,2603.217z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1165.698,395.571c105.955-32.198,218.313-49.539,334.652-49.539
                c603.642,0,1100.397,466.329,1148.987,1057.652h24.582c-9.973-125.317-39.686-247.058-88.736-363.029
                c-59.301-140.2-144.192-266.111-252.313-374.234c-108.122-108.123-234.034-193.013-374.234-252.313
                c-145.159-61.397-299.348-92.528-458.285-92.528c-117.145,0-231.704,16.934-341.975,50.41L1165.698,395.571z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1892.773,2609.323l-8.553-23.179c-11.475,4.063-23.037,7.935-34.675,11.641l7.324,23.586
                C1868.891,2617.551,1880.859,2613.54,1892.773,2609.323z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2478.611,2108.471c-6.734,10.768-13.649,21.407-20.723,31.932l21.545,12.817
                c7.303-10.908,14.43-21.931,21.361-33.078L2478.611,2108.471z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2083.276,2493.331c-10.54,6.202-21.186,12.245-31.937,18.116l12.174,21.736
                c11.139-6.066,22.172-12.306,33.096-18.725L2083.276,2493.331z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1985.896,2544.547c-11.051,5.15-22.201,10.124-33.439,14.934l9.774,22.748
                c11.643-4.971,23.195-10.109,34.64-15.433L1985.896,2544.547z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2035.172,2520.115c-10.807,5.683-21.714,11.194-32.719,16.541l10.981,22.268
                c11.406-5.521,22.71-11.211,33.905-17.086L2035.172,2520.115z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2262.018,2363.711c-9.271,8.177-18.665,16.215-28.197,24.092l16.51,18.826
                c9.845-8.156,19.568-16.479,29.17-24.972L2262.018,2363.711z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1935.545,2566.574c-11.272,4.614-22.643,9.033-34.092,13.297l8.556,23.188
                c11.823-4.393,23.596-8.963,35.307-13.748L1935.545,2566.574z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2219.574,2399.375c-9.617,7.7-19.354,15.257-29.221,22.651l15.508,19.671
                c10.2-7.652,20.284-15.473,30.246-23.471L2219.574,2399.375z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2175.574,2432.904c-9.946,7.213-20.006,14.277-30.188,21.176l14.448,20.444
                c10.536-7.137,20.961-14.446,31.264-21.925L2175.574,2432.904z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2130.11,2464.242c-10.255,6.711-20.617,13.271-31.094,19.664l13.335,21.129
                c10.85-6.606,21.589-13.384,32.215-20.341L2130.11,2464.242z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2600.148,2439.238l75.949-13.516c201.208-254.912,321.304-576.818,321.304-926.781
                c0-115.553-13.102-228.042-37.882-336.077l-60.659-36.077c31.612,118.866,48.481,243.74,48.481,372.559
                C2947.342,1858.194,2816.589,2186.49,2600.148,2439.238z"/>
            <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M580.414,2613.735C259.956,2348.547,55.777,1947.793,55.777,1499.347
                c0-574.105,334.625-1070.053,819.473-1303.448H762.825C309.303,453.146,3.297,940.298,3.297,1498.942
                c0,445.579,194.667,845.69,503.59,1119.93L580.414,2613.735z"/>
        </g>
        <polyline fill="#00AEEF" points="2002.903,440.99 1996.871,572.727 2118.385,500.173  "/>
        <polyline fill="#00AEEF" points="934.566,2378.094 815.834,2435.484 937.477,2507.826     "/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

how can I make my svg animated (circle line 4 left to right and the circle line 3 is right to left)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolate the element or group `g` that you want to animate and make sure it has an ID (*if you name your layers in Illustrator it should export those names out as ID's I believe*)

Define a keyframe animation (*unprefixed for brevity*)

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Apply it to the element in question (Only one for this example)

```
#XMLID_1_ {
  animation: spin 12s linear infinite;
  animation-direction:reverse; /* note below */
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

NB: The animation is defined to work clockwise. However, it can be utilised to run in the opposite direction with the `animation-direction` property.

```css
#Layer_1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#XMLID_1_ {
  animation: spin 12s linear infinite;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  transform-origin: center;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 3000 3000" enable-background="new 0 0 3000 3000" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <g>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1375.631,54" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1375.631,54
                C633.068,117.25,50.095,740.004,50.095,1498.942s582.974,1381.693,1325.536,1444.94" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1625.068,2943.882
                c742.562-63.251,1325.534-686.003,1325.534-1444.94S2367.63,117.25,1625.068,54" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1625.068,2943.882" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1625.068,54" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M357.221,1395.021" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M2643.479,1440.251h77.141
                c-30.628-647.454-565.236-1162.983-1220.269-1162.983c-655.036,0-1189.644,515.529-1220.271,1162.983h77.142" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M2643.479,1440.251" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M357.221,1557.633" />
      <path fill="none" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-width="7" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M357.221,1557.633h-77.142
                c30.627,647.452,565.235,1162.982,1220.271,1162.982c655.032,0,1189.641-515.53,1220.269-1162.982h-77.141" />
    </g>

    <g id="XMLID_1_">
      <g>
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2903.798,1498.94c0,15.417-0.269,30.797-0.758,46.129h-122.333c0.551-15.308,0.831-30.688,0.831-46.129
                    c0-53.941-3.361-107.1-9.866-159.304l120.658-21.286C2899.959,1377.854,2903.798,1438.104,2903.798,1498.94z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2779.937,1563.408h122.407c-3.338,74.248-12.422,147.519-27.228,219.505l-120.67-21.273
                    C2767.931,1697.185,2776.575,1630.98,2779.937,1563.408z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2889.885,1300.158l-120.608,21.273c-9.341-67.121-23.914-132.591-43.28-195.995l115.327-41.972
                    C2863.281,1154.303,2879.48,1226.644,2889.885,1300.158z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2750.558,1779.575l120.744,21.285c-15.674,71.474-36.983,141.65-63.893,210.214l-115.23-41.936
                    C2716.35,1908.095,2735.936,1844.764,2750.558,1779.575z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2835.761,1065.97l-115.242,41.947c-20.784-64.688-46.568-127.15-76.913-186.922l106.39-61.436
                    c15.649,30.528,30.174,61.594,43.488,93.076C2809.267,989.937,2823.352,1027.727,2835.761,1065.97z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2685.296,1986.146l115.303,41.972c-2.335,5.722-4.694,11.431-7.115,17.128
                    c-25.895,61.253-56.35,120.891-90.839,178.035l-106.317-61.375C2630.291,2105.972,2660.086,2047.238,2685.296,1986.146z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2741.511,843.286l-106.329,61.387c-31.788-60.47-68.27-118.103-108.97-172.423l94.2-79.041
                    c15.1,19.977,29.686,40.309,43.672,61.008C2692.154,755.772,2718.024,798.93,2741.511,843.286z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2586.693,2177.519l106.366,61.411c-9.378,15.099-19.036,30.026-28.976,44.747
                    c-30.639,45.334-64.052,89.017-99.874,130.622l-94.104-78.968C2512.824,2285.877,2551.837,2233.122,2586.693,2177.519z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2609.25,638.648l-94.152,79.004c-42.008-54.442-88.296-105.412-138.349-152.421l79.09-94.25
                    c12.52,11.639,24.831,23.499,36.897,35.565C2534.231,548.041,2573.196,592.263,2609.25,638.648z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2458.027,2349.134l94.128,78.992c-19.171,21.677-38.989,42.779-59.419,63.208
                    c-36.151,36.152-74.37,70.41-114.3,102.467l-78.98-94.116C2356.479,2454.058,2409.551,2403.687,2458.027,2349.134z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2442.305,458.572l-79.028,94.176c-56.374-51.459-117.357-97.954-182.24-138.801l61.435-106.402
                    c14.378,8.974,28.585,18.192,42.608,27.667C2340.193,372.452,2392.863,413.788,2442.305,458.572z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2285.055,2511.043l79.004,94.152c-25.687,20.087-52.046,39.281-78.979,57.486
                    c-33.084,22.349-67.182,43.304-102.1,62.768l-61.362-106.28C2178.933,2587.26,2233.546,2551.07,2285.055,2511.043z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2226.834,297.935l-61.387,106.329c-58.696-35.785-120.486-66.986-184.856-93.113l41.96-115.254
                    c8.057,3.24,16.089,6.517,24.109,9.903C2108.67,232.037,2169.029,262.919,2226.834,297.935z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2105.528,2627.972l61.374,106.305c-39.196,21.188-79.358,40.518-120.242,57.805
                    c-25.626,10.845-51.483,20.87-77.562,30.112l-41.911-115.156C1988.929,2685.152,2048.506,2658.646,2105.528,2627.972z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2005.471,189.172l-41.935,115.205c-64.053-24.917-130.586-44.833-199.125-59.247l21.273-120.67
                    C1860.459,139.902,1933.826,161.505,2005.471,189.172z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1909.852,2713.04l41.923,115.181c-68.331,23.242-138.129,41.055-209.101,53.403l-21.261-120.597
                    C1786.002,2749.755,1848.954,2733.629,1909.852,2713.04z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1767.7,120.866l-21.273,120.609c-67.438-13.167-136.747-21.029-207.486-23.131V96.023
                    C1616.318,98.089,1692.682,106.402,1767.7,120.866z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1703.318,2764.06l21.261,120.584c-61.093,9.793-123.03,15.552-185.639,17.227v-122.32
                    C1594.69,2777.887,1649.561,2772.642,1703.318,2764.06z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1520.602,2779.965v122.284c-6.749,0.086-13.498,0.146-20.247,0.146
                    c-68.135,0-135.525-4.816-201.961-14.377l21.273-120.585c59.039,8.362,119.362,12.703,180.688,12.703
                    C1507.116,2780.137,1513.864,2780.075,1520.602,2779.965z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1520.602,95.644v122.284c-6.737-0.11-13.485-0.183-20.247-0.183c-76.375,0-151.199,6.736-223.931,19.61
                    l-21.273-120.597c80.374-14.146,162.239-21.273,245.204-21.273C1507.104,95.485,1513.864,95.546,1520.602,95.644z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1301.512,2764.72l-21.261,120.572c-73.821-11.615-146.431-29.11-217.476-52.449l41.935-115.206
                    C1168.285,2738.336,1234.037,2754.156,1301.512,2764.72z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1237.118,120.059l21.261,120.609c-71.473,13.718-140.843,33.401-207.584,58.501l-41.923-115.193
                    C1083.242,156.138,1159.458,134.792,1237.118,120.059z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1087.301,2711.83l-41.911,115.168c-30.761-10.551-61.216-22.165-91.353-34.917
                    c-38.867-16.444-77.085-34.734-114.435-54.699l61.374-106.305C960.468,2662.706,1022.735,2689.774,1087.301,2711.83z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M991.73,190.529l41.935,115.206c-67.194,26.383-131.649,58.281-192.779,95.13L779.5,294.56
                    c56.093-33.621,114.545-63.379,174.538-88.76C966.544,200.518,979.113,195.432,991.73,190.529z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M884.838,2622.348l-61.362,106.28c-36.923-20.368-72.953-42.375-107.858-65.946
                    c-20.943-14.158-41.531-28.927-61.729-44.222l79.041-94.201C781.064,2560.374,831.814,2593.177,884.838,2622.348z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M763.826,304.097l61.411,106.354c-60.788,37.827-118.188,80.618-171.628,127.786l-78.98-94.127
                    c44.686-39.246,91.866-75.703,140.99-108.897C731.464,324.514,747.553,314.146,763.826,304.097z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M718.321,2513.121l-78.992,94.152c-46.128-35.884-90.105-74.664-131.368-115.939
                    c-11.859-11.858-23.511-23.938-34.954-36.225l94.262-79.103C613.899,2425.583,664.404,2471.455,718.321,2513.121z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M560.912,456.31l79.016,94.152c-47.241,42.889-91.254,89.262-131.673,138.679l-94.091-78.955
                    c29.55-36.079,60.873-70.715,93.798-103.64C525.15,489.356,542.829,472.607,560.912,456.31z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M554.774,2362.546l-94.189,79.041c-45.016-49.649-86.56-102.552-123.971-157.91
                    c-4.976-7.373-9.854-14.794-14.695-22.264l106.476-61.473C466.172,2257.525,508.474,2311.894,554.774,2362.546z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M402.622,624.454l94.127,78.979c-44.258,55.702-83.968,115.157-118.592,177.814l-106.28-61.362
                    c20.026-36.165,41.629-71.461,64.736-105.669C357.374,683.493,379.429,653.527,402.622,624.454z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M418.43,2184.512l-106.391,61.436c-40.297-63.979-75.483-131.307-104.825-200.702
                    c-0.379-0.88-0.734-1.76-1.101-2.641l115.364-41.996C348.876,2064.758,381.373,2126.218,418.43,2184.512z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M263.087,835.987l106.305,61.375c-33.291,62.34-61.582,127.737-84.322,195.652l-115.218-41.935
                    c11.175-33.169,23.633-65.996,37.363-98.443C223.976,912.999,242.657,874.047,263.087,835.987z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M314.375,1983.676l-115.267,41.959c-29.085-71.754-52.009-145.293-68.722-220.275l120.768-21.297
                    C266.84,1852.857,288.077,1919.563,314.375,1983.676z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M164.105,1068.513l115.267,41.948c-21.249,66.619-37.191,135.586-47.302,206.411l-120.597-21.261
                    C122.647,1218.477,140.191,1142.651,164.105,1068.513z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M247.206,1766.139l-120.695,21.286c-15.344-73.441-24.746-148.229-28.157-224.017h122.407
                    C224.208,1632.558,233.17,1700.277,247.206,1766.139z" />
        <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M108.966,1313.791l120.622,21.273c-6.883,53.672-10.429,108.371-10.429,163.877
                    c0,15.441,0.281,30.821,0.831,46.129H97.657c-0.489-15.332-0.758-30.712-0.758-46.129
                    C96.899,1436.551,100.946,1374.773,108.966,1313.791z" />
      </g>
      <g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M714.827,655.783c11.458-10.68,23.14-21.121,35.024-31.334l-15.507-19.669
                c-12.194,10.472-24.206,21.196-36.011,32.197L714.827,655.783z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M763.862,612.598c12.066-10.043,24.33-19.854,36.803-29.407l-14.468-20.471
                c-12.806,9.794-25.414,19.873-37.839,30.211L763.862,612.598z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M624.686,749.812c10.139-11.834,20.502-23.47,31.103-34.881l-17.471-17.935
                c-10.941,11.743-21.607,23.689-32.024,35.815L624.686,749.812z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M511.15,907.297c7.944-13.233,16.137-26.299,24.59-39.182l-20.097-15.006
                c-8.707,13.253-17.127,26.691-25.289,40.292L511.15,907.297z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M583.821,800.284c9.433-12.346,19.11-24.493,29.024-36.44l-18.404-17.013
                c-10.229,12.288-20.208,24.754-29.902,37.416L583.821,800.284z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M479.525,963.445c7.167-13.606,14.6-27.049,22.288-40.327l-20.789-13.89
                c-7.907,13.66-15.561,27.478-22.923,41.47L479.525,963.445z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M451.192,1021.114c6.369-13.93,13.011-27.71,19.913-41.336l-21.417-12.742
                c-7.096,14.013-13.917,28.188-20.468,42.518L451.192,1021.114z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M545.939,852.842c8.701-12.812,17.659-25.435,26.855-37.873l-19.293-16.045
                c-9.482,12.794-18.696,25.771-27.639,38.928L545.939,852.842z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M924.925,500.173c13.651-7.895,27.481-15.517,41.478-22.862l-11.009-22.323
                c-14.395,7.517-28.62,15.319-42.664,23.411L924.925,500.173z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M421.698,1026.322c-2.088,4.762-4.153,9.538-6.181,14.333c-49.052,115.971-78.764,237.712-88.737,363.029
                h24.582c10.607-129.072,42.545-252.194,92.308-365.804L421.698,1026.322z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2649.337,1594.199c-14.892,181.217-71.867,350.691-161.118,498.604l22.143,11.651
                c28.249-47.074,53.238-96.199,74.821-147.227c49.051-115.972,78.764-237.713,88.736-363.028H2649.337z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M668.395,701.584c10.813-11.277,21.856-22.334,33.116-33.167l-16.5-18.813
                c-5.772,5.546-11.508,11.143-17.184,16.817c-5.697,5.698-11.315,11.457-16.882,17.252L668.395,701.584z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1094.746,393.312l8.554,23.185c14.823-5.455,29.793-10.602,44.893-15.458l-7.327-23.594
                C1125.403,382.407,1110.029,387.696,1094.746,393.312z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M982.714,468.923c14.093-7.11,28.343-13.955,42.758-20.497l-9.788-22.779
                c-14.826,6.697-29.476,13.704-43.964,20.984L982.714,468.923z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1042.238,440.99c14.483-6.297,29.123-12.298,43.906-18.009l-8.56-23.2
                c-11.896,4.584-23.742,9.346-35.523,14.328c-3.21,1.357-6.403,2.744-9.599,4.129L1042.238,440.99z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M869.068,534.63c13.164-8.647,26.523-17.022,40.055-25.138l-12.21-21.801
                C883,496,869.26,504.583,855.71,513.461L869.068,534.63z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M815.328,572.162c12.636-9.364,25.465-18.48,38.488-27.333l-13.369-21.186
                c-13.38,9.071-26.574,18.427-39.58,28.057L815.328,572.162z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2447.525,2155.576c-7.213,10.371-14.592,20.611-22.13,30.73l20.854,13.936
                c7.796-10.49,15.42-21.095,22.854-31.828L2447.525,2155.576z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2302.807,2325.975c-8.901,8.639-17.933,17.145-27.109,25.497l17.455,17.918
                c9.47-8.641,18.817-17.45,28.038-26.424L2302.807,2325.975z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2414.304,2200.953c-7.667,9.958-15.492,19.789-23.472,29.486l20.082,14.996
                c8.265-10.052,16.355-20.23,24.266-30.531L2414.304,2200.953z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2341.849,2286.224c-8.513,9.092-17.163,18.054-25.961,26.865l18.36,16.972
                c9.121-9.147,18.071-18.421,26.857-27.822L2341.849,2286.224z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2379.047,2244.527c-8.102,9.531-16.348,18.936-24.748,28.195l19.244,16.006
                c8.705-9.605,17.237-19.339,25.6-29.195L2379.047,2244.527z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1832.029,2603.217c-105.083,31.622-216.431,48.635-331.68,48.635
                c-603.643,0-1100.398-466.33-1148.989-1057.652h-24.582c9.974,125.315,39.686,247.057,88.737,363.028
                c59.299,140.2,144.19,266.11,252.312,374.233c108.124,108.124,234.035,193.012,374.234,252.315
                c145.16,61.396,299.35,92.527,458.288,92.527c116.091,0,229.645-16.63,339.001-49.513L1832.029,2603.217z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1165.698,395.571c105.955-32.198,218.313-49.539,334.652-49.539
                c603.642,0,1100.397,466.329,1148.987,1057.652h24.582c-9.973-125.317-39.686-247.058-88.736-363.029
                c-59.301-140.2-144.192-266.111-252.313-374.234c-108.122-108.123-234.034-193.013-374.234-252.313
                c-145.159-61.397-299.348-92.528-458.285-92.528c-117.145,0-231.704,16.934-341.975,50.41L1165.698,395.571z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1892.773,2609.323l-8.553-23.179c-11.475,4.063-23.037,7.935-34.675,11.641l7.324,23.586
                C1868.891,2617.551,1880.859,2613.54,1892.773,2609.323z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2478.611,2108.471c-6.734,10.768-13.649,21.407-20.723,31.932l21.545,12.817
                c7.303-10.908,14.43-21.931,21.361-33.078L2478.611,2108.471z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2083.276,2493.331c-10.54,6.202-21.186,12.245-31.937,18.116l12.174,21.736
                c11.139-6.066,22.172-12.306,33.096-18.725L2083.276,2493.331z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1985.896,2544.547c-11.051,5.15-22.201,10.124-33.439,14.934l9.774,22.748
                c11.643-4.971,23.195-10.109,34.64-15.433L1985.896,2544.547z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2035.172,2520.115c-10.807,5.683-21.714,11.194-32.719,16.541l10.981,22.268
                c11.406-5.521,22.71-11.211,33.905-17.086L2035.172,2520.115z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2262.018,2363.711c-9.271,8.177-18.665,16.215-28.197,24.092l16.51,18.826
                c9.845-8.156,19.568-16.479,29.17-24.972L2262.018,2363.711z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M1935.545,2566.574c-11.272,4.614-22.643,9.033-34.092,13.297l8.556,23.188
                c11.823-4.393,23.596-8.963,35.307-13.748L1935.545,2566.574z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2219.574,2399.375c-9.617,7.7-19.354,15.257-29.221,22.651l15.508,19.671
                c10.2-7.652,20.284-15.473,30.246-23.471L2219.574,2399.375z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2175.574,2432.904c-9.946,7.213-20.006,14.277-30.188,21.176l14.448,20.444
                c10.536-7.137,20.961-14.446,31.264-21.925L2175.574,2432.904z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2130.11,2464.242c-10.255,6.711-20.617,13.271-31.094,19.664l13.335,21.129
                c10.85-6.606,21.589-13.384,32.215-20.341L2130.11,2464.242z" />
    </g>
    <g id="outer-markers">
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M2600.148,2439.238l75.949-13.516c201.208-254.912,321.304-576.818,321.304-926.781
                c0-115.553-13.102-228.042-37.882-336.077l-60.659-36.077c31.612,118.866,48.481,243.74,48.481,372.559
                C2947.342,1858.194,2816.589,2186.49,2600.148,2439.238z" />
      <path fill="#00AEEF" d="M580.414,2613.735C259.956,2348.547,55.777,1947.793,55.777,1499.347
                c0-574.105,334.625-1070.053,819.473-1303.448H762.825C309.303,453.146,3.297,940.298,3.297,1498.942
                c0,445.579,194.667,845.69,503.59,1119.93L580.414,2613.735z" />
    </g>
    <polyline fill="#00AEEF" points="2002.903,440.99 1996.871,572.727 2118.385,500.173  " />
    <polyline fill="#00AEEF" points="934.566,2378.094 815.834,2435.484 937.477,2507.826     " />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Note: *Transformations* of this type are often interpreted differently in various browsers, what wokrs for one may not work for another.**

The above works in Chrome but quite differently in Firefox. There are a number of SO questions on this point

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bdpKdE)

[**CSS-Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=animate%20SVG) has a range of articles on this too. Especially, this one on [**Transforms**](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/)

Comment: Nope...didn't say it did. There is no single solution in CSS for this. That's why it's usually left to Javascript libraries to sort out ...like [**Greensock**](http://greensock.com/products/)

Comment: any svg javascript/jquery animator plugin you could suggest that could cater my needs?

Comment: See Greensock as I mentioned above.